# PHP & AJAX - Submit form doesn't work because of AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I'm making [this](http://www.heinesiebrand.nl/contact/#url=http%3A//www.heinesiebrand.nl/contact/) contact form. The site itself uses AJAX to load the content in the main window. The problem with my form is that when the user clicks on submit and the data passes validation, it loads the page to main instead to itself to reach the actual mailing script.

Is there any way to pass this??

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, but I have a feeling that the answer will involve either 'return false', 'action="script.php"' or maybe both.

Answer (score 0):

take the action our of the form opening tag

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Prototype.js library, you could just call `event.stop()` on a passed `event` object, on form submit.